# Passing a string variable to AddWithParameters method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to insert a query and I want to pass the logged in User ID as a parameter, the UserID is a string.

I tried to do this:

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=project;Integrated Security=true;");
            var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Invoice VALUES (SYSDATETIME(),'@id',0)");
           cmd.Connection= con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id",userId);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

I am getting an error on  `cmd.Parameters.Add("@id",userId);` that the userId needs to be of the data type "SqlDbType". How could I pass this var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the value directly when adding a parameter, and the [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameterCollection_Add_System_String_System_Data_SqlDbType_) overload that takes 2 parameters required the name of the parameter and it's type. You can either do this:

```
var p = cmd.Paramaters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar);
p.Value = userId;
```

Or:

`cmd.Paramaters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userId;`